# WordPress checkbox to map

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a website using WordPress. There is a plug in that displays pins from a database on a map, the short code is as follow
[locations_map category="scouts"]
with the category set as scouts it obviously shows all pins relating to that.
I have manually added scouts but want it so I have several different check boxes that the users tick and it then sends that info to the short code.

as its a WordPress site I have issues of using PHP, so again have to put in a plugin that handles PHP side of things

So far I have managed to add check boxes direct on page with this

```
<form action="" method="post">
scouts: <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="scouts"> 
Guides: <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="Guide"> 
<input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

and then using a PHP short code, I have this set as PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['num']))
{
    echo htmlentities($_POST['num']);
}
```

?>

This then reloads on the same page showing only one of the selected checkboxes?
What I'm trying to do is get the info from several checkboxes passed into the short code below

```
enter code here   [locations_map category="xxxxHERExxx" ]
```

So total code on WordPress page

```
[xyz-ips snippet="front"] <form action="" method="post">
scouts: <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="scouts"> 
Guides: <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="Guide"> 
<input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
</form>

[locations_map category="scouts" ]
```

as you can probably guess I'm no coder and am randomly changing bits trial and error to get to this far.

andy

Comment: bit of progress, i now have the map loading from $_num but this then loads all options every time. even if they are not checked. [locations_map category=$_POST'num']  how do I put  if(isset($_POST['num'] into short code. thanks